# Drawind Dynamic series and points with Highchart and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I try to get several series of data from employees and get them drawed through HighCharts.
I don't know the company till the user click, so then I get trough ajax all the employees and their data (points).

I have a select box where I choose the company. Once done, I call via AJAX/jQuery the server to get data added to HighChart:

```
    $("#company").change(function(){     
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: xxxxx,
                async: false,
                data: { company: company},
                success: function(data) {
                     $.each(data, function(val, text) {
                        alert (val);
                        alert (text);
                        chart2.addSeries({
                            name: val,
                            data: text
                        });
                    });   
                }
            ...
```

Data I get from the server trough Firebug is in this way:

```
{"Employee1":[["1356908400000","10.00"],["1359586800000","11.00"],  ["1362006000000","12.00"],["1364684400000","13.45"]],"Employee2":[["1356908400000","10.00"],["1359586800000","11.00"],["1362006000000","12.00"],["1364684400000","13.45"]]}
```

Employee1 and Employee2 should be the series.
However when I call addseries method I get this error:

```
Uncaught Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14
```

It seems data doesn't like to Highcharts.
When I debug through alerts, I get this:

```
alert (val)->Employee1
alert (text)=1356908400000,10.00,1359586800000,11.00,1362006000000,12.00,1364684400000,13.45
```

This example is working fine when I put data without ajax.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer :-)

text is an array so I need another $.each to read it and format the result:

```
success: function(data) {
                    $("html").css('cursor','auto');
                    $.each(data, function(val, text) {
                        counter = 0;
                        $.each(text, function() {
                            if (counter==0) {
                                employee_data=  "[" + this + "]";
                            }
                            else{
                                employee_data= employee_data + "," + "[" + this + "]";
                            }
                            counter=1
                        });

                        employee_data = "["+ + "]";
                        chart.addSeries({
                            name: val,
                            data: employee_data
                        });
                    });   
                },
```